# How do I insert a mergefield into an If..else statement in VBA using Word MailMerge?

Tags: vba, ms-word, mailmerge, mergefield

The below macro will input the field heading followed by the field value. The If statement should check the value of the field and if its greater than 30 the actual value is given, otherwise a zero.

Instead of the value appearing if it's true, I just get the actual text I've typed, not it's value.

```
   Sub Macro1()
      Dim doc As Word.Document
      Dim dtField As Word.MailMergeDataField
      Dim sFieldName As String
      Dim sFieldActualName As String
      Dim j As Integer

      Set doc = ActiveDocument
      j = 1

      For Each dtField In doc.MailMerge.DataSource.DataFields

        sFieldActualName = doc.MailMerge.DataSource.FieldNames(j).Name
        sFieldName = dtField.Name
        Selection.TypeText Text:=sFieldActualName + ": "
'---------------------------------------------------------------------------
            doc.MailMerge.Fields.AddIf Range:=Selection.Range, MergeField:= _
                sFieldName, Comparison:=wdMergeIfGreaterThan,_
 CompareTo:="30", TrueText:="{MERGEFIELD sFieldName}", _
                FalseText:="0"
'---------------------------------------------------------------------------
        Selection.TypeParagraph
        j = j + 1

      Next

    End Sub
```

Please let me know if i need to clarify anything.

Edit: Sample data I'm using from excel

```
one   two   three   four    five
85    50     63      50      41
52    10     84      10      15
85    25     63      35      10
```

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "the actual text I've typed". Typed where/when?

Comment: Sorry, where I've put TrueText:="{MERGEFIELD sFieldName}" inside the if statement, the word document will just print {MERGEFIELD sFieldName} rather than 85 or whatever value the field should have.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, the only way to insert a nested field set is to insert the fields directly. Nested fields are tricky - there are a couple of approaches "out there", in the internet. The following is the one I use.

In this variation, the outer-most field is inserted with placeholder text for the inner field code(s). The placeholder text is the field code with typed brackets (not the Ctrl+F9 kind).

The outer field is sent to the Function `GenerateNestedField` along with the placeholder string. The function locates the placeholder in the field's code and inserts the real field in its place.

I had to modify my standard code to work with the fact that you're inserting a MailMergeField for the If field. It's necessary to convert the MailMergeField to a regular Word.Field which I do by selecting the inserted field, then taking the first Field in the Fields collection.

```
Sub IfPlusMergeField()
    Dim doc As word.Document
    Dim sFieldCode As String, sFieldName As String
    Dim fldMerge As word.MailMergeField
    Dim fldIf As word.Field

    Set doc = ActiveDocument
    sFieldName = dt.FieldName
    sFieldCode = "{Mergefield " & sFieldName & "}"
    Set fldMerge = doc.MailMerge.Fields.AddIf(Range:=Selection.Range, _
                   MERGEFIELD:=sFieldName, Comparison:=wdMergeIfGreaterThan, _
                   CompareTo:="30", TrueText:=sFieldCode, _
                   FalseText:="0")
    fldMerge.Select
    Set fldIf = Selection.Fields(1)
    Debug.Print GenerateNestedField(fldIf, sFieldCode)
End Sub

'Returns the changed field code
Function GenerateNestedField(fldOuter As word.Field, _
                             sPlaceholder As String) As String

    Dim rngFld As word.Range, doc As word.Document
    Dim bFound As Boolean
    Dim sFieldCode As String

    Set doc = fldOuter.Parent

    Set rngFld = fldOuter.code
    rngFld.TextRetrievalMode.IncludeFieldCodes = True
    bFound = rngFld.Find.Execute(findText:=sPlaceholder)
    'Get the field code from the placeholder by removing the { }
    sFieldCode = Mid(sPlaceholder, 2, Len(sPlaceholder) - 2)
    If bFound Then
        doc.Fields.Add rngFld, word.WdFieldType.wdFieldEmpty, sFieldCode, False
    End If
    'Debug.Print fldOuter.code

    GenerateNestedField = fldOuter.code
End Function
```

Comment: For a demo of how to insert nested fields directly, see: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/898e6ff6-e9e5-4440-b64d-72aaea4b350d/programatically-add-footer-to-the-last-page-in-a-word-document-using-word-interop-in-c?forum=worddev