# Excel Vba to Word: How to write a pagenumber into a textframe?

Tags: excel, ms-word, textfield, vba

I am writing an Excel VBA macro that copies text to a Word for Windows file and 
adds formatting to it later.

It uses a .dotx template that contains a logo. In the lower left corner is a textbox with a serial-number. The text of the serial-number is written 
vertically (from the bottom upwards).

Using trial and error I managed to write one serial-number to the textbox 
using:

```
serialnumber = "abc1x"
wdoc.Sections(1).Headers(wdHeaderFooterEvenPages).Shapes(2).TextFrame.TextRange.text 
= serialnumber
```

So I found the right object to write to.
Now I get the same serialnumber on every page.

My goal is to get an increasing serialnumber on the pages:
The serial-number has the shape:

- On page 1:       abc1x
- on page 2:        abc2x
- on page 3:           abc3x
- ...
- on page 10:     abc10x

It's the page number surrounded by 2 strings.

On a different project I did something similar.
I wrote "Page 1 of 10" etc. with the following script:

```
    Dim uRange As Object
    Dim uneven As Object

    Set uneven = wdoc.Sections(1).Footers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary)
    Set uRange = wdoc.Sections(1).Footers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range
    uRange.Delete

    uneven.Range.InsertAfter "Page "
    uRange.SetRange Start:=uneven.Range.End + 1, End:=uneven.Range.End + 1
    wdoc.Sections(1).Footers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range.Fields.Add 
Range:=uRange, Type:=wdFieldEmpty, text:= _
    "PAGE  \* Arabic ", PreserveFormatting:=True

    uRange.SetRange Start:=uneven.Range.End + 1, End:=uneven.Range.End + 1
    uneven.Range.InsertAfter " of "
    uRange.SetRange Start:=uneven.Range.End + 1, End:=uneven.Range.End + 1

    wdoc.Sections(1).Footers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range.Fields.Add 
Range:=uRange, Type:=wdFieldEmpty, text:= _
     "NUMPAGES  \* Arabic ", PreserveFormatting:=True
```

How do I insert the text around the Page field in the TextBox?

(Side note: What is the difference between the range and rangetext object?)

Remarks:
I will have to apply the solution to the even and uneven pages seperately.
That doesn't pose a problem.
To make matters more difficult:
I am obliged to keep the text-field, because it comes from the hands of 
the corporate identity folks.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by `rangetext` object. There is `Range.Text`  which is the actual string content "in" a particular `Range`. `Text` is also the default property of Word's `Range` object, so if you leave it away in VBA and assign (or try to read) a string, VBA will *assume* you mean the `Text` property and use that. But it's better to be specific...

Comment: If you mean `TextFrame.TextRange` that's just the name of the Range property inside a `Shape` object. This is shared across all Office applications. I don't know whether it's named differently simply because the developers of this part of the object model liked it better, or whether to distinguish the property from `ShapeRange` and Word and Excel's `Range` objects...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of ways to go about this. All involve "collapsing" the target `Range` before inserting the next thing (text or field code).

Some time ago, I wrote a set of generalized functions so that I could insert any combination of text and field codes comfortably, without having to "tweak" for each combination.

First define the `Range` object. If there might be any content you want to keep, collapse it. The procedures `InsertNewText` and `InsertNewField` take the target `Range` and the text to insert, respectively the field code for the field to be inserted. The collapsing of the `Range` is done in these procedures and is passed back to the calling procedure for the next step.

```
Sub InsertTextAndFields()
    Dim rngContent As Word.Range

    Set rngContent = wdoc.Sections(1).Headers( _
        wdHeaderFooterEvenPages).Shapes(2).TextFrame.TextRange
    rngContent.Collapse wdCollapseEnd

    Set rngContent = InsertNewText(rngContent, "abc")
    Set rngContent = InsertAField(rngContent, "Page")
    Set rngContent = InsertNewText(rngContent, "x")

End Sub

Function InsertNewText(rng As word.Range, newText As String) As word.Range
    rng.Text = newText
    rng.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
    Set InsertNewText = rng
End Function

Function InsertAField(rng As word.Range, _
                      fieldText As String) As word.Range

    Dim fld As word.Field
    Dim rngField As word.Range

    Set fld = rng.Document.Fields.Add(Range:=rng, _
              Text:=fieldText, PreserveFormatting:=False)

    Set rngField = fld.result
    rngField.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
    rngField.MoveStart wdCharacter, 1
    Set InsertAField = rngField
End Function
```

Comment: Great it worked and the solution is neatly packaged!
Eine meisterhafte Loesung. (the work of a true master)

Comment: I need one more tweak:
The counting is 1, 2, 3..., 8, 9, A, B, C, ....
instead of 1, 2,3, ..., 8,9, 10, 11

    On page 1:       abc1x
    on page 2:        abc2x
    on page 3:        abc3x
    ...
    on page 10:     abcAx



Can I combine your solution with logic in tex-fields?

it should look like
{IF {PAGE} < 10 ""{PAGE \* Arabic }"" ""{ PAGE \* ALPHABETIC }""}

I get the formula into the text-field,
(if I look at it in the word-dokument the formula is in the properties 
of the textfield)
 but i doesn't display the numbers.

Comment: @Ratilius You should never edit a question in a way that invalidates the answer - and this was very clearly *not* in the original problem statement. Creating *nested* fields is an entirely different kettle of fish. Look at my Answer in this discussion https://stackoverflow.com/a/49805695/3077495, in particular the function GenerateNestedField

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out. 
Asking a new question would have been the preferred way?
I will change back the question later on my pc. the interface on my mobile is very clumsy.

Comment: @Ratilius It's alright, I've rolled it back for you. Asking a new question would be preferred, yes, IF the information in the link doesn't solve the problem for you. FWIW all the information to solve it is there - it's just a matter of fitting it together.